# How can I do this effectively?

Tags: python, python-3.x

This problem:

Input: 123456

Result:

```
1+2+3+4+5+6 = 21
2+1 = 3
```

Return: 3

This is my code:

```
num = input()
print(sum(list(map(int, list(num)))))
```

I don't know how to do until it is 1 digit.

Comment: what you've tried to accomplish that and where you get `2+1`? is there any logic behind it?

Comment: Show what you tried as properly formatted code in the question.

Comment: Put some effort in before you ask people to do your homework for you. [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: 2+1 is from the return of latest summation.

Comment: @March, I've modified my answer, please have a look now, It is more readable and concise now.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

One way to do it using `sum()`, `list comprehension` and `recursion`,

```
def simulated_sum(input):
    """This is a recursive function
    to find the simulated sum of an integer"""

    if len(str(input)) == 1:
        return input
    else:
        input_digits = [int(x) for x in str(input)]
        latest_sum = sum(input_digits)
        return simulated_sum(latest_sum)

input = int(input('Enter a number'))    
print(simulated_sum(input))
```

**DEMO:** https://rextester.com/WCBXIL71483

Answer (score -1):

Try this (example in IPython):

```
In [1]: s = '123456'
Out[1]: '123456'

In [2]: digits = [int(j) for j in s]
Out[2]: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

In [3]: s = str(sum(digits))
Out[3]: '21'
```

Repeat steps 2 and three until `len(s) == 1`.

Answer (score -1):

You can try this:

```
s = input()
while(len(s)>1):
    s = str(sum(list(map(int,s))))
```

Answer (score -1):

One way:

```
while len(str(ans))>1:
    ans = sum(map(int, str(ans)))
```

Full code:

```
num = 45637
ans = num

while len(str(ans))>1:
    ans = sum(map(int, str(ans)))

print(ans)
```

Output for input 45637:

```
7
```

Answer (score -2):

Is this what you want? (instructions unclear):

```
def myfunction(number):
    total = 0
    answertotal = 0
    for i in str(number):
        total += int(i)
    for i in str(total):
        answertotal += int(i)
    return answertotal

myfunction(123456)
```

This function returns 3